# Rei origami swans and giraffes, Linear Programming

Tags: linear-programming

Rei volunteers to bring origami swans and giraffes to sell at a charity crafts fair. It takes her three minutes to make a swan and six minutes to make a giraffe. She plans to sell the swans for $\$4$ dollars each and the giraffes for $\$6$ each. If she only has $16$ pieces of origami paper and can’t spend more than one hour folding, use a geometric approach to find how many of each animal should Rei make to maximize the charity’s profit?

### So far, I have:

s: $\#$ of swans

g: $\#$ of giraffe

p: profit, p= 4s+6g

Constraints:

time it takes to make origami (in minutes): 3s+6g $ \leq$ 60

paper: s+g=16

Number of swans: s $\geq$ 0

Number of giraffes: g $\geq$ 0

After this I am unsure as to where to go. We are instructed that we are to use LINGO, but I am unsure how to use the program nor has the teacher taught us, any help is appreciated and thank you.

Comment: Test for profit at the vertices of [this](https://puu.sh/FZHEc.png) graph.

Comment: Why  don´t  you give any reply (including accepting an answer)? This behaviour doesn´t motivate people to help you.

Answer (score 1):

If you are to use a geometric approach, I would make the number of swans the horizontal axis and the number of giraffes the vertical axis.  Each constraint is a line that divides the feasible from unfeasible region.  The sheets of paper form the line $s+g=16$ and the feasible region is below the line.  There is another line for the maximum time folding, plus $s \ge 0, g \ge 0$.  That gives you a feasible quadrilateral.  Now you know the optimal point is at one of the corners of the region, so compute the profit at each one and you have the best point.